# Question on replacing polar equations with equivalent Cartesian equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I have this polar equation:

$$r=4\csc\theta$$

My initial idea was to plug into the cartesian equations for $x$ and $y$, so I got:

$$x=4\csc\theta\cos\theta=4\cot\theta$$

$$y=4\csc\theta\sin\theta=4$$

But the solution says to do this:

$$r=\frac{4}{\sin\theta}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\sin\theta$ yields:

$$r\sin\theta=4$$

Since $y=r\sin\theta$, we get $y=4$.

I understand that I also got $y=4$ (which is just horizontal line) but I also got $x=4\cot\theta$.

How would I know to just not use the value that I got for $x$? The answer just says $y=4$ which is a horizontal line.

Comment: $x=4\cot\theta$ is exactly the same line as $y=4$

Comment: $x=4\cot\theta=4/\tan\theta=4/(y/x)=4x/y$ so $y=4$.

Comment: $x=4\cot\theta$ correctly gives the relationship between $x$ and $\theta$ but it is not a *Cartesian* equation.